# Magento Wholesale buying

Tags: magento

I have this idea to make a product page that lists all the products on the site, Perhaps paginatied, and have them all have a quantity box on the right side of them.

This way, people who stock my product can go to this page, enter the quantities for all the products they need and click "Add to cart" at the top or bottom of the page.

Saving the stockist time by adding 40 of each product they want etc.

Has this been done before? Can it be done?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Of course this is possible. In terms of magento quite everything is possible. If your question "Has this been done before?" aims to an extension-suggestion. Sorry, but i don't know one.

But in simplest case a "small" custom module could do the job. Simply add a custom attribute to the categories (e.g. wholesale = yes|no), override the catalog/category/view.phtml by your module-layout-update and check this attrib within that "new" view. If it is "yes" list all products out of this category in the way described above.

Processes of "add to cart" with the right qty out of a categoryview exist already but you need to trigger them e.g. by a custom javasscript just before the page swaps. and you slightly have to mod the "add to cart" itself to prevent jumping into the cart afterwards. Its just an example, would work for non-configurable/non-optioned products at least.

If it has to be an own page listing all products of the shop, your module has to provide a bit more up front (controller, viewblock, etc.) but that more could be also helpful with implementing own logic, eg. collecting all qty in a session first and ask later for "add to cart"